# Opening an html div element using # in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, url

I have a page containing two tabs (Home|Action).

When i hover the Actions tab, the URL appear with #tab_action :

[image]

And then when i click , it open the related tab content:

[image]

When i enter manually the URL :

localhost:8088/hse/public/observation/3/show#tab_action

It opening the home tab not the Action tab.

How can i make the above URL opening the Action tab , same as when i click on action tab.

Comment: onload read the hash

Comment: @epascarello  can you pls explain more, i am using a bootstrap tabs

Answer (score 0):

onload/document ready read the hash, if it is there use it.

```
$(function(){
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  if (hash && hash.length>1) {
    $(hash).click()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `window.location.hash`(the url hash) on page load and switch tabs in js code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange.[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) you can find the documentation

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}

function locationHashChanged() {
    if (location.hash === "#tab_action") {
        somecoolfeature();
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

Comment: Please _do not_ use `target.onsomething = ...` but `target.addEventListener('something' ...)`!